# Advises to wrap a 3d triangulator for three.js

Tags: three.js, triangulation, delaunay

I have surfed the web looking for 3D worlds triangulate code for use with `three.js`. I know there is the shape object, but it only can use 2D and paths. I'd have outer polygon, points, holes and 'forced' polylines.

How to deal with this and three? Do I have to use another JS framework?

Ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to triangulate a near-planar or planar 3d polygon?

If you have a near-planar or planar 3d-polygon, it can be triangulated by 'projecting' it down to 2d, running the triangulation, then 'de-projecting' back to 3d. Many libraries (such as CGAL, http://www.cgal.org ) do this by choosing one simple 'plane', the xy, yz, or xz plane, projecting down, doing the triangulation, and then 'projecting back up'.

The trick is that if you aren't adding any new points, you don't actually have to 'project back up', you just have to list your old 3d points in a new data structure, indicating which belong to which triangles. And if your code is very clever, you don't even need to 'convert' to 2d, you just need to fool your triangulation algorithm into thinking, for example, that y is x and z is y, (assuming you have projected onto the yz plane).

Thus, if you have a near-planar 3d polygon, and a good 2d-triangulation algorithm (three.js' shape might be sufficient, but if not, maybe some combination of Angus Johnson's Clipper might help, especially if you want to integrate stray points, lines, etc.), you just need to write a bit of 'glue' code to do the projection 3d->2d, and de-projection 2d->3d. Orientation (clockwise vs counterclockwise) of output can be a bit tricky, but it's not the most difficult thing in the world to program.

Good luck.

Comment: Finally I decided to use poly2tri. Thanks